# `npm install mongodb` arises error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, bson

i just try to learn mongodb , when i try to install mongodb for node , i got the error as below shown.

By the way ,my enviroment:`ubuntu 10.04` + `node v0.6.9`.Also i use the nvm ,which switch the node version locally.

```
zhkzyth@geek:~/codeRep/Nodejs---MongoDB$ npm install mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.5

> bson@0.1.5 install /home/zhkzyth/codeRep/Nodejs---MongoDB/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> node install.js || (exit 0)

================================================================================
=                                                                              =
=  Attempting to build bson c++ extension                                      =
=   Windows: no build will be attempted as binaries are prepackaged            =
=   Unix: on failure the package will still install without the C++ extension  =
=                                                                              =
================================================================================
node-gyp clean
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/zhkzyth/codeRep/Nodejs---MongoDB/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
gyp ERR! node -v v0.6.9
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.8.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
make: *** [clean] 错误 1
child process exited with code 2
mongodb@1.2.8 ./node_modules/mongodb 
└── bson@0.1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you're able to install it on Node.js versions earlier than 0.6.19. This [issue](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/850) was brought up on the mongodb github issues page, and has been upgraded to fail due to Node switching to use gyp to build extensions.

Comment: ye~When i use switch to the most recent version, i finally installed it.